# Minimum number of changes that we need to make so that there will be only one island in matrix

Tags: matrix, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, connected-components

A Matrix containing 0s and 1s is provided, all 0s are water and 1s are land. A group of connected 1s forms an island. If one change can convert one 0 to 1 then find out minimum number of changes that we need to make so that there will be only one island in matrix.

for example:

Matrix->

```
        1 0 1

        0 0 0

        1 0 1
```

Minimum number of changes to convert into single island is 1.
Convert (2,2) to 1.

I was asked this question in an interview. I used dfs to find out the number of islands. But can't get an approach to solve further.

Comment: Can a change convert a one into a zero?

Comment: I don't think you will need that .